# PHP CSV encoding not utf-8

Tags: php, csv, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I am generating a CSV file with PHP and saving it on the hard disk (I do not want a download). The database charset is `utf8_general_ci` and there are chars in there like the degrees sign (`°`), which show up perfectly in PHPmyadmin. These chars need to be saved in the CSV file. Everything I do is in UTF-8, but the file gets saved with the encoding `ISO-8859-1`. If I start using the `utf8_encode` function, other chars show up (`Â`) when I convert it back to `UTF-8` in excel or any other text editor. I do not know what is going wrong and I have spent hours to track it down, without success.

I have tried `SET NAMES utf8` just to be sure it is `UTF-8`, but that just causes more strange characters and no `UTF-8` encoding. Using MySQLi's `set_charset` does the same. With the header as `Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8` the CSV still does not have utf-8 as default encoding, nor with any of these combinations.

Some code:

```
header("Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8");
$rMysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "database");
$rCSV = fopen("test_".time().".csv", 'w');

$aCSVdata = array($var1, $var2, $var3);
fputcsv($rCSV, $aCSVdata, ",", "\"");

fclose($rCSV);
```

That is pretty much all is happening. Just normal CSV data, only with special chars such as `°` and `Ø`.

Comment: Check if your PHP script is in UTF-8. Also, how do you know that the file is in ISO-8859-1?

Comment: @Passerby Damn, I have tried so many things that I just simply forgot to put the header with the content-type for the file back.. I could really slap myself right now. It seems that I need to give the file the UTF-8 header AND `utf_encode` the data though.

Comment: @Passerby and to answer your question on how you can see the encoding: I changed the extension to `txt` and opened it in FireFox. If you go to view > character encoding you will see the current encoding selected. You might need to press alt to get the menu up though.

Comment: Opening it in some program and that program detecting the file as ISO-8859 doesn't mean anything. It just means the program didn't know any better and chose ISO, it doesn't mean the file is necessarily encoded in that format. And please don't use `utf8_encode`. See [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) and [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/).

Comment: @deceze But I did know it wasn't utf8 so that was one thing. Anyway, those are very interesting articles, I will take my time and read them, thanks for that. I have put back the `SET NAMES utf8`, and the `utf8_encode` was not needed anymore, so I got rid of that.

Comment: Well, now it suddenly seems that it does NOT have the correct encoding as default. It just understood what it should be.. Anyway, I'm completely clueless right now why it doesn't have the correct encoding. If I remove the `SET NAMES utf8` it does show the chars correctly, but in ISO format, though I have the file header at `Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8`

Comment: @DaveRandom Thanks for that. I am using MySQLi, but when I set charset via that function, it still does not give the default charset ast UTF-8 in the CSV.

Comment: @Rune *Never* use `SET NAMES` in PHP. Use `mysql_set_charset()` (the C-API function) instead. MySQLi and ext/mysql both expose this directly (although we all know you shouldn't use ext/mysql, don't we boys and girls ;-) ), PDO exposes it through the `charset` DSN parameter

Comment: @Rune Sorry for re-posting, but I put "should" instead of "shouldn't" and it's quite an important distinction! Can you show some code please?

Comment: It's really unclear how you determine that your data is not UTF-8 encoded. Try `echo bin2hex($yourData)`. If the "°" character results in `C2B0`, it's UTF-8 encoded alright. If you dump that as is into a file, that will be UTF-8 encoded as well. Check the file with a hex editor to be sure. Once that's settled, worry about how the application you're trying to open it with recognizes the correct encoding.

Comment: @DaveRandom no problem, I'm not using mysql anyway and I do know the difference. I have added some code. As you can see, it's just the normal way to write CSVs..

Comment: @Rune OK, well there's nothing wrong there (the `text/html` threw me off for a minute, but you're not outputting the file so it's not *wrong*, it's just useless) - how are you viewing the file - in which program? If you are actually outputting the file (sending it to the client) you should use `text/csv` as the content type. You could try writing a byte order mark to the beginning of the file, but this might create more problems than it solves.

Comment: @deceze The text should be `punthoek 118 °` (with some more text), only it shows with an `Â` in front of it. This is the hex part of that string: `70756e74686f656b2031313820c2b0`. As you can see, the last part is `c2b0`, so it is outputting the char correctly. The question is where that strange char comes from..

Comment: Your data is UTF-8 encoded. The problem is likely that the program you're trying to view this file with does not interpret it as UTF-8 but in some other encoding. The data is fine, the interpreting program is dealing with it wrong.

Comment: @Rune It's about the way it is rendered. The data is right, whatever you are using to view it is rendering it wrong.

Comment: @deceze that's odd. I thought Excel (and the OpenOffice one too) would display it correctly. Notepad does show it correctly. It seems I have found another reason to be annoyed by Microsoft...

Comment: The Office suite is **the worst** when it comes to encodings. They notoriously suck at it. Try including a BOM, MS products really like it.

Comment: @deceze Ok, thanks for that info. Can you post it as an answer for the sake of the Q&A format? Then I'll accept it too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

...long story of the comments short...

Microsoft Office is **the worst** when it comes to encodings. It **notoriously sucks at it**.

(I.e. everything was fine except Excel.)